# bash file in docker isn't executing

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, docker

I want my bash file to run whenever I the run the docker image, so firstly I created the Dockerfile inside a new directory say `demo` and in that directory demo I created a new directory `home` and in that directory I’ve my bash file - `testfile.sh`.
Here is my docker file -

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Aman Kh
COPY . /home
CMD /home/testfile.sh
```

On building it with command - `sudo docker build -t amankh99/hello .`
the following output was received -

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.584kB
Step 1/4 : FROM ubuntu
—> 0458a4468cbc
Step 2/4 : MAINTAINER Aman Kh
—> Using cache
—> 98fbe31ed233
Step 3/4 : COPY . /home
—> Using cache
—> 7e52ff3439e2
Step 4/4 : CMD /home/testfile.sh
—> Using cache
—> 1d2660df6387
Successfully built 1d2660df6387
Successfully tagged amankh99/hello:latest
```

But when I run it with command

```
sudo docker run --name test -it amankh99/hello
```

it says

> bin/sh: 1: /home/testfile.sh: not found

After having build successfully why it is unable to found the file.
I want to convert this container in image and want to push on docker hub, so that when I can run this with simple run command as we run the hello-world(sudo docker run hello-world) , I get my bash file executed, so what changes in dockerfile can I do to acheive this.

Comment: `RUN chmod +x /home/testfile.sh` after copy

Comment: @aerokite: If the mode was not executable, it would give: `/bin/sh: 1: /home/testfile.sh: Permission denied`

Comment: Looks like the `testfile.sh` is not in the same directory as your Dockerfile. Try: `sudo docker run -it amankh99/hello /bin/bash -c "ls -l /home"`.

Comment: yea.. you are right..

Comment: Can you check `RUN ls -la /home` after copy ?

Comment: His file was not copied, so he is getting this problem.

Comment: @abeltre1, probable, but not certain. It's possible to get a "not found" error from a file that does in fact exist -- if its interpreter doesn't exist; if its interpreter is an executable that links a shared library that doesn't exist; etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OP's Description**

> I created the Dockerfile inside a new directory say **demo** and in that directory demo I created a new directory **home** and in that directory I’ve my bash file - **testfile.sh**.

So according to your description

```
demo/
+--- Dockerfile
+--- home/
     +--- testfile.sh
```

You need to COPY `home` directory into `/home`

```
FROM ubuntu
COPY home /home
CMD /home/testfile.sh
```

If you do this `COPY . /home`, your `home/testfile.sh` will be copy into `/home/home/testfile.sh`

If you want copy only your `testfile.sh`, then do this

```
COPY home/testfile.sh /home/
```

Comment: Read carefully, he has a home directory, then in that directory, he has the script. @marcolz

Comment: Right, this is the most likely problem. @aerokite

Comment: Thanks for the credit. @aerokite which i did not get for pointing out this.

Comment: @abeltre1, I didn't get you

Answer (score 1):

It either **can** find the file and it just does not know what to do with it because the interpreter of your script ( `#!....` on the first line of your script) is not present in your docker image, or it **cannot** find the file because it was not copied.

You can verify this by passing `/bin/bash` as final argument to your docker run command, and run `ls -l /home/testfile.sh` and/or `/home/testfile.sh` on the prompt.